# How to count how many conditions an observation meets using R?

Tags: r

If I have a date set with lots of binary variables, all with values o/1. I want to create a new column, and add by one if the observation is 1 of one binary variable, add by two if it has 1 of two binary variables...

Such as:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1  1   1  0  1 
0  0   1  0  0
0  0   0  0  0
```

I want to have

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5  count
  1  1   1  0  1   4
  0  0   1  0  0   1
  0  0   0  0  0   0
```

Comment: Use `df$count <- rowSums(df)`

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset contains only the binary variables you are interested in, you can use

```
df$count <- rowSums(df)
```

Otherwise, please provide a more detailed description of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `Reduce` with `+`

```
df$count <- Reduce(`+`, df)
```